# Huge difference between matched requests/impressions in certain countries

Tags: android, admob

I have recently developed a Unity 3D application which includes AdMob ads. I have developed the application so its shows an interstitial ad on the start of every level.

However, there is a huge difference in the matched requests and the impressions shown in the particular area of China.

There is a report from yesterday below:

https://postimg.org/image/5z70scilz/

Anyone experiencing something like this?

Comment: The reason depends on your implementation, are you requesting and presenting the ad at the same time, or first loading It and when time comes display it? China users may have slow Internet connection which effect display time

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had that problem at the start with that, i was loading the ads and then showing them after a given time. This affected all countries.  However i changed that and now i am requesting the ad and i have implemented the onLoad() listener so i request the ad and when it gets loaded it is displayed automatically. Now the problem is solved in all countries except china.

Answer (score 1):

This means that there was only ads available 101 times out of 489 requests. Ie there aren't that many ads available for that region of China.

The normal solution to this is to use mediation to provide backup ad networks that might fill that gap.